# Trying to connect to a FireStore database but getting "Program type already present: okio.Buffer$2"

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issue with dependencies, somewhere I have a dual dependency for an okio.Buffer$2 and possibly an okio.AsyncTimeout (It has popped up in the attempts to solve a problem but I'm having trouble isolating the issue). Here are my dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation files('ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
implementation files('build/libs/unirest-java-1.4.10-SNAPSHOT withDependency-ShadedForAndroid.jar')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1'
```

I have exhausted many forms and attempts as well as hours in this. If anyone has any thought please leave a comment. This project has also implemented facebook signin, google signin, and firestore. I believe one of those 3 are giving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One can exclude it from `implementation`:

```
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0") {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okio"
}
```